# STM32F769 Header Power Input

Tags: arduino, power-supply, stm32, stm32f7

As a new STM32 user, I would like to know if it is possible to connect unregulated voltages (6.2V to 9V) to a Power input pin on the headers as same as on the Arduino?

The board I'm using is STM32F769 Discovery Kit with the touchscreen. I would like to power it with a nonregulated battery pack, just to make it portable.

Comment: What does the datasheet for the board say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to page 15 of the [specifications](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/group0/7c/c9/c0/5f/4e/9b/44/eb/DM00276557/files/DM00276557.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00276557.pdf) (Assuming that's the same kit) you can use a 7-12V DC which may fit your requirement if your supply is over 7V.

[image]